# How to add custom properties to AdvancedMarkerElement in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-advanced-marker-element

I am migrating map markers to `AdvancedMarkerElement` and I want to add custom properties to `AdvancedMarkerElement`.

Like this:

```
new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  map: this.map,
  position: data.position,
  dataWHD: data.data,
})
```

This produces the following error:

`Unknown property 'dataWHD' of AdvancedMarkerElement`

How can I do this?

Comment: No, the above code should definitely NOT produce the error you mentioned. If it does, provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please have a look i just updated the code. This is the error `Unknown property 'dataWHD' of AdvancedMarkerElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add custom properties directly to the `AdvancedMarkerElement` constructor.

Instead, you can transfer your custom properties via the `AdvancedMarkerElement` `content` property so you can build your own markers with whatever data you need.

Below is an example from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/advanced-markers-html).

#### Method 1

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const center = { lat: 37.43238031167444, lng: -122.16795397128632 };
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  for (const property of properties) {
    const AdvancedMarkerElement = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
      map,
      content: buildContent(property),
      position: property.position,
      title: property.description,
    });
    AdvancedMarkerElement.addListener("click", () => {
      toggleHighlight(AdvancedMarkerElement, property);
    });
  }
}

function toggleHighlight(markerView, property) {
  if (markerView.content.classList.contains("highlight")) {
    markerView.content.classList.remove("highlight");
    markerView.zIndex = null;
  } else {
    markerView.content.classList.add("highlight");
    markerView.zIndex = 1;
  }
}

function buildContent(property) {
  const content = document.createElement("div");

  content.classList.add("property");
  content.innerHTML = `
    <div class="icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-icon fa-${property.type}" title="${property.type}"></i>
        <span class="fa-sr-only">${property.type}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <div class="price">${property.price}</div>
        <div class="address">${property.address}</div>
        <div class="features">
        <div>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bed fa-lg bed" title="bedroom"></i>
            <span class="fa-sr-only">bedroom</span>
            <span>${property.bed}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bath fa-lg bath" title="bathroom"></i>
            <span class="fa-sr-only">bathroom</span>
            <span>${property.bath}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-ruler fa-lg size" title="size"></i>
            <span class="fa-sr-only">size</span>
            <span>${property.size} ft<sup>2</sup></span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
  return content;
}

const properties = [
  {
    address: "215 Emily St, MountainView, CA",
    description: "Single family house with modern design",
    price: "$ 3,889,000",
    type: "home",
    bed: 5,
    bath: 4.5,
    size: 300,
    position: {
      lat: 37.50024109655184,
      lng: -122.28528451834352,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "108 Squirrel Ln &#128063;, Menlo Park, CA",
    description: "Townhouse with friendly neighbors",
    price: "$ 3,050,000",
    type: "building",
    bed: 4,
    bath: 3,
    size: 200,
    position: {
      lat: 37.44440882321596,
      lng: -122.2160620727,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "100 Chris St, Portola Valley, CA",
    description: "Spacious warehouse great for small business",
    price: "$ 3,125,000",
    type: "warehouse",
    bed: 4,
    bath: 4,
    size: 800,
    position: {
      lat: 37.39561833718522,
      lng: -122.21855116258479,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "98 Aleh Ave, Palo Alto, CA",
    description: "A lovely store on busy road",
    price: "$ 4,225,000",
    type: "store-alt",
    bed: 2,
    bath: 1,
    size: 210,
    position: {
      lat: 37.423928529779644,
      lng: -122.1087629822001,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "2117 Su St, MountainView, CA",
    description: "Single family house near golf club",
    price: "$ 1,700,000",
    type: "home",
    bed: 4,
    bath: 3,
    size: 200,
    position: {
      lat: 37.40578635332598,
      lng: -122.15043378466069,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "197 Alicia Dr, Santa Clara, CA",
    description: "Multifloor large warehouse",
    price: "$ 5,000,000",
    type: "warehouse",
    bed: 5,
    bath: 4,
    size: 700,
    position: {
      lat: 37.36399747905774,
      lng: -122.10465384268522,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "700 Jose Ave, Sunnyvale, CA",
    description: "3 storey townhouse with 2 car garage",
    price: "$ 3,850,000",
    type: "building",
    bed: 4,
    bath: 4,
    size: 600,
    position: {
      lat: 37.38343706184458,
      lng: -122.02340436985183,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "868 Will Ct, Cupertino, CA",
    description: "Single family house in great school zone",
    price: "$ 2,500,000",
    type: "home",
    bed: 3,
    bath: 2,
    size: 100,
    position: {
      lat: 37.34576403052,
      lng: -122.04455090047453,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "655 Haylee St, Santa Clara, CA",
    description: "2 storey store with large storage room",
    price: "$ 2,500,000",
    type: "store-alt",
    bed: 3,
    bath: 2,
    size: 450,
    position: {
      lat: 37.362863347890716,
      lng: -121.97802139023555,
    },
  },
  {
    address: "2019 Natasha Dr, San Jose, CA",
    description: "Single family house",
    price: "$ 2,325,000",
    type: "home",
    bed: 4,
    bath: 3.5,
    size: 500,
    position: {
      lat: 37.41391636421949,
      lng: -121.94592071575907,
    },
  },
];

initMap();
```

```css
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

:root {
  --building-color: #FF9800;
  --house-color: #0288D1;
  --shop-color: #7B1FA2;
  --warehouse-color: #558B2F;
}

#map {
  height: 180px;
}

.property {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #263238;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  width: 30px;
}

.property::after {
  border-left: 9px solid transparent;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
  border-top: 9px solid #FFFFFF;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.property .icon {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.property .icon svg {
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.property .details {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.property .address {
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.property .features {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

.property .features > div {
  align-items: center;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 10px;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*
 * Property styles in highlighted state.
 */
.property.highlight {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 80px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  width: auto;
}

.property.highlight::after {
  border-top: 9px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.property.highlight .details {
  display: flex;
}

.property.highlight .icon svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.property .bed {
  color: #FFA000;
}

.property .bath {
  color: #03A9F4;
}

.property .size {
  color: #388E3C;
}

/*
 * House icon colors.
 */
.property.highlight:has(.fa-house) .icon {
  color: var(--house-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-house) {
  background-color: var(--house-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-house)::after {
  border-top: 9px solid var(--house-color);
}

/*
 * Building icon colors.
 */
.property.highlight:has(.fa-building) .icon {
  color: var(--building-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-building) {
  background-color: var(--building-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-building)::after {
  border-top: 9px solid var(--building-color);
}

/*
 * Warehouse icon colors.
 */
.property.highlight:has(.fa-warehouse) .icon {
  color: var(--warehouse-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-warehouse) {
  background-color: var(--warehouse-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-warehouse)::after {
  border-top: 9px solid var(--warehouse-color);
}

/*
 * Shop icon colors.
 */
.property.highlight:has(.fa-shop) .icon {
  color: var(--shop-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-shop) {
  background-color: var(--shop-color);
}

.property:not(.highlight):has(.fa-shop)::after {
  border-top: 9px solid var(--shop-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/js/all.js"></script>
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>
```

#### Method 2

Alternatively, you can also set custom properties after you have created the `AdvancedMarkerElement` but not in the constructor.

This uses `v: "beta"` because `gmpClickable` is currently only available in the beta version (March 2024).

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
async function initMap() {
  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  const center = {
    lat: 37.43238031167444,
    lng: -122.16795397128632
  };
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });

  const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    title: 'My custom marker',
    gmpClickable: true
  });

  marker.customProp = 'custom property';

  marker.addListener("gmp-click", () => {
    alert('clicked ' + marker.customProp)
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/js/all.js"></script>
<script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "beta"});</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

AdvanceMarkerElement content is HTMLElement so you can use it's function as [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and then get it with [Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
here you have my use case of creating google maps Advance Markers following its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/graphic-markers?hl=es-419):

```
async function initMapaTipo(
    localizaciones: ILocalizacionesF[],
): Promise<void> {
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = (await google.maps.importLibrary("marker")) as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;

    marcadores.value = [];
    const usingIconsStore = useIconsStore();
    localizaciones.forEach((localizacion) => {
        if (localizacion.agrupaciones) localizacion.agrupacionesF = localizacion.agrupaciones.split(",");
        const glyphSvgPinElement = new PinElement();
        const glyphImg = document.createElement("img");
        glyphImg.src = usingIconsStore.setIcon(localizacion.icono);
        glyphSvgPinElement.glyph = glyphImg;
        const advancedMarker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: {
                lat: localizacion.lat!,
                lng: localizacion.lng!
            },
            content: glyphSvgPinElement.element,
            title: localizacion.agrupacionesF![0]
        });
        marcadores.value.push(advancedMarker);
        advancedMarker.setAttribute("agrupacionesArr", localizacion.agrupaciones);
        advancedMarker.setAttribute("prv_codigo", String(localizacion.prv_codigo));
        google.maps.event.addListener(advancedMarker, "click", async function () {
            let marca: string = await pideFichaMovil(localizacion.prv_codigo, advancedMarker);
            let plantilla: string = usingIconsStore.setInfoWindow(marca)!;
            infowindow.value?.setContent(plantilla);
            infowindow.value?.open(map.value, advancedMarker);
            cerrarBuscador.value = false;
            map.value?.setCenter(advancedMarker.position!);
        });
    });
    markerClusterC.addMarkers(marcadores.value);
}
```

notice that you can only set string type in
Element.setAttribute
so you'll need to proccess any other type to string and reverse.

Comment: The least you could do when answering a question is to provide a complete and working code snippet and to write code in English.

Comment: The least I could do is share my code to help anyone who need it, and is what I did. So many others helped me out in the same way =)